# Extract hours and minutes from a string python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a string that is in the format of `'00:00'` displaying the time. It can be any time. I would like to extract the hours and minutes into individual variables.

Comment: `hour, min = '00:00'.split(':')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may want `hours` and `minutes` be integers:

```
hours, minutes = map(int, "00:00".split(':'))
```

---

### How this works

1. `str.split(delim)` splits a `str` using `delim` as delimiter. Returns a list: `"00:00".split(':') == ["00", "00"]`
2. `map(function, data)` applies `function` to each member of the iterable `data`. `map(int, ["00","00"])` returns an iterable, whose members are integers.
3. `a, b, c = iterable` extracts 3 first values of `iterable` and assigns them to variables called `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 5):

For parsing times, use the `datetime`-class:

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.strptime('23:43', '%H:%M')
print time.hour, time.minute
```

Answer (score 3):

If it always in the same format you could `split` it by the colons:

```
hours, minutes = "00:00".split(":")
```

Comment: less than ideal as hours and minutes variables will be of type str

Comment: @leggewie Which is the correct behavior for this case. The questioner just asked how to split them. Converting them to another type is trivial from here. It's just either doing it each one separately (for example `hours = int(hours)`), by mapping `hours, minutes = map(int, "00:00".split(':'))` or by list comprehension `hours, minutes = [int(x) for x in "00:00".split(':')]`

Comment: I just pointed that that the solution you presented as is before had this gotcha of the variables being str.  Your solution with map and and list comprehension don't have this gotcha and thus are preferable.  But don't pretend they are the same solution.

Comment: @leggewie There are no gotchas. If you want to split a string into two variables, then of course they'll be strings. What you suggest is preferable is not correct as it depends on the use case. For simple arithmetic, converting them to int's are correct. But if you want to do more complex math you'd probably want to convert them to floats. Or if you're just going to display them, store them in a text file, parse/serialize them, or send them over the internet then they should be strings. So no, they're not the same solution as the latter is not what's being asked.

Answer (score 1):

The [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function is your friend here:

```
>>> time = "11:23"
>>> hours, minutes = time.split(":")
>>> print hours
11
>>> print minutes
23
```

Comment: less than ideal as hours and minutes variables will be of type str